# Consulta EntityFramework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc, entity-framework

Cambié los códigos de la pregunta anterior, para usar un string que me facilite las cosas. Conseguí lo que buscaba. 
Ahora lo que se genera es la siguiente excepción :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type ProvidusCuotas is not part of the model for the current context.'
```

**Controlador:**

```
public ActionResult Index(){
            SQL sql = new SQL();
            List<ProvidusCuotas> lista = sql.cargarDatos();
            return View(lista);
        }
        public ActionResult PrintViewToPdf(){
            var report = new ActionAsImage("Index");
            return report;
        }

public ActionResult PrintPartialViewToPdf(string id){
            using (PDFPrinter db = new PDFPrinter()) {
                ProvidusCuotas customer = db.SQLs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.titulo == id); //justo en esta línea se genera la excepción
                List<ProvidusCuotas> lista = new List<ProvidusCuotas>();
                lista.Add(customer);
                var report = new PartialViewAsPdf("Detalle", lista);
                return report;
            }
        }
```

Clase SQL:

```
public List<ProvidusCuotas> cargarDatos(){
            List<ProvidusCuotas> salida = new List<ProvidusCuotas>();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("conexion");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,max(Cuota) FROM V_CuetaWeb GROUP BY titulo, apellido, nombre ORDER BY titulo ASC", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = comand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read()){
                string titulo = Convert.ToString(dr.GetDouble(0));
                string nombre = dr.GetString(1);
                string cuota = Convert.ToString(dr.GetDouble(2));
                ProvidusCuotas p = new ProvidusCuotas(titulo,nombre, cuota);
                salida.Add(p);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return salida;
        }
```

Clase PDF Printer:

```
public partial class PDFPrinter : DbContext
    {
        public PDFPrinter()
            : base("name=PDFPrinter")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        //public virtual DbSet<V_CuetaWeb> V_CuetaWeb { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<ProvidusCuotas> SQLs { get; set; }
    }
```

El problema surge cuando en el INDEX clickeo sobre este enlace:

```
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Azul","PrintPartialViewToPdf", new { id = item.titulo})
            </td>
```

La idea es que al presionar sobre ese link, se cargue un pdf con la información que necesito pero surge la excepción mencionada anteriormente

Comment: ¿Por qué le pusiste *cerrada* al título de tu pregunta?

Comment: Es que no se si se puede cerrar la pregunta, porque modifiqué todo el código. Para no editar toda la pregunta lo que hice fue poner (cerrada) y hacer otra pregunta con el código nuevo para que no se genere tanta confusión @Aprendiz

Comment: Si tienes mas información que agregar considero que mejor la agregues a esta, ya que esta quedando abierta pues no se indica si se encontró o no la solución

Comment: Vale, modificaré esta @Aprendiz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tienes el contexto con la entidad mapeada porque no usas linq

```
var result = from cuenta in db.NombreEntidad
              group cuenta by cuenta.Titulo into g
              select new V_CuetaWeb()
               {
                  Titulo = g.Key,
                  Cuota = g.Max(x=>x.Cuota)
               };
```

asi generaras un sql aplicando la consulta en lugar de tener un string que define el sql

Comment: Porque me sale este error: 
`System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'ProvidusModel1.V_CuetaWeb' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'`

Comment: que version de  EF estas usando? mapeas las entidades a una tabla, de donde sale la variable "db" ?

Comment: EntityFramework   {6.2.0} 
Y para tu pregunta, la variable db viene del la clase PDFPrinter, editaré la pregunta para que se vea esa clase

Comment: Lo que sucede es que debo generar un pdf luego de realizada la carga por eso el uso de la clase pdfprinter desde donde traigo la vista V_CuetaWeb

Comment: ehh pero si mapeas una vista esa query la pones en la vista no la defines como string para ejecutar como query, solo usarias `var result = db.V_CuetaWeb.ToList();` eso es todo porque mapeas la view en el dbcontext

Comment: porque le pones `PDFPrinter ` como nombre del dbcontext? es un nombre extraño

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar esto :

```
            var resultado = (from cuenta in db.V_CuetaWeb
                             group cuenta by new { cuenta.titulo } into cuentaGrupo
                             select new
                             {
                                 cuentaGrupo.Key.titulo,
                                 max = cuentaGrupo.Max(c => c.cuota)
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Intenté como me dijiste y lo que obtuve fue esto: 

`System.InvalidOperationException: El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[< >f__AnonymousType2`2[System.Double,System.Nullable`1[System.Double]]]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProviEntity.V_CuetaWeb]'.`

Comment: La vista está así: `@model  List<ProviEntity.V_CuetaWeb>`